# Using the firebase admin sdk in vscode extension - with native library dependency

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, firebase-admin

I'm writing a VSCode extension that relies on Firebase Admin SDK. I'm trying to get it configured but when I run and activate the plugin, the extension host process throws a module loading error:

`Could not find module:  .../node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v54-darwin-x64/grpc_node.node`

When firebase admin was installed it built a version of the binary dependency but using a different version: node-v51. So the library is there but the version is different.

I probably need to somehow build the node-v54-darwin/x64 library when the Firebase sdk is installed via npm, but I'm not familiar with native modules, pre-gyp etc so I'm fumbling through it.

Does anyone know how to coerce npm to build the version required by the vscode host process for the grpc dependency?

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you figured out the problem?